# using a variable in GetElementByID

Tags: jquery, variables, toggle

I have a scenario where I am building a series of DIVS and each has an ID assigned in the syntax 'div1', 'div2', etc etc....

the divs all appear fine and I can see their ID's are all assigned properly...

I am trying to use the following code to then allow a click (where the ID is passed) to toggle the display of the corresponding div:

```
$("#page-wrap li a").click(function(id){
 var thisid = ('#'+$(this).attr('id').toString());
 alert(thisid);
 document.getElementById(thisid).hide();
}
```

but the error console shows that the getelementbyid has a null value.

what am I missing?  I tried forcing the thisid var to a string but that didnt work either.

thanks for any light anyone can shed on this for me.

Comment: You don't use the `#` id selector with `.getElementById()`, just the plain `id`. I would do `document.getElementById(this.id).style.display = 'none';`. Note how I'm directly accessing the `this` to get it's `id`, not `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: Can we see a bit of the HTML in relation to the anchor and div - I'm not sure I understand the question. Based on what I see, you're trying to get the ID of the anchor, then hide the anchor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you mixing jQuery and standard DOM methods?

Something like this should work instead:

Given the markup:

```
<a href="#someDiv">Hide the div</a>
<div id="someDiv">DIV to be hidden</div>


$("a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reload
  $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
});
```

Comment: sweet.... I managed to hobble together a solution based on your response.... yes, I was indeed mixing standard DOM with jquery (frustrated and throwing a bunch of stuff against the wall in hopes I'd latch onto some clues to see what I was doing wrong)...  thanks to all who replied.  I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing plain dom calls with jQuery. For consistency, try this:

```
$("#page-wrap li a").click(function(id){
    var thisid = ('#'+$(this).attr('id'));
    alert(thisid);
    $(thisid).hide();
});
```

Comment: Also, the toString() on the second line should not be necessary. Updating answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the same ID on both your `<div>` and `<a>` tags. Instead, you can pass the ID of your `<div>` via data attributes of your anchor:

```
<div id="div2">this is div2</div>
<a href="#" data-id="div2">click here to hide div2</a>
```

Then, the click handler will look like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  // $(this).data('id') == "div2"
  $(document.getElementById($(this).data('id'))).hide();
  return false;
});
```